# How to specific after save function with variables in Rails 4 model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm trying to create little function to calculate benefit after record been saved.
I have 3 controllers and 3 models: Buy, Sell, Stock
Buy and Sell belongs_to Stock

I would like to save some calculation in database after save in Sells table.
So I did try to do that in Sell model

```
class Sell < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :stock
after_save :calculate_selled_stock, :reset_to_zero, :calculate_benefit
before_save :check_amount

#validate :validate_amount
validates :amount, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal: 0 }



 private

    def calculate_benefit
    self.update_attribute(:zysk, 400)
    end


    def calculate_selled_stock
         Stock.find(stock_id)
         stock.increment! :value, totalprice
         stock.decrement! :amount, amount
    end

  def check_amount
    item = Stock.find(stock_id)

    return false unless item
    errors.add(:amount, "Error message") 
    item.amount_available?(self.amount)

  end



  def reset_to_zero
  item = Stock.find(stock_id)
  item.update_attributes(:amountvalue => 0, :amoutbuys => 0) if item.amount_zero?(self.amount)
  end

end
```

But it will go for infinity loop after you try create.
How can I modify this and for example add some variables?

```
def calculate_benefit
var1 = 400
var2 = var1*20
self.update_attribute(:zysk, var2)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are running into an issue is because you keep updating your stock which then kicks off the `after_save` methods. I think a simple change would be to change `after_save` to `after_update`.

There are other ways to solve this issue and would recommend you looking into them because these call back hooks after can really cause issues down the road and cause frustrations with trying to find a work around. [Here](http://samuelmullen.com/2013/05/the-problem-with-rails-callbacks/) is an example about how you could handle callbacks.

I would recommend changing a few other things, like you do not need to do

```
item = Stock.find(stock_id)
```

you can instead just call stock and it nows how to find the correct stock because you specified above

```
belongs_to :stock
```

Comment: Thanks for replay. I only check this on create.I changed as you suggested but it is still the same. It must be some mistake on my code somewhere.
SystemStackError (stack level too deep)...

Comment: If this is a public repo I can take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with use `after_save` and `attribute_update` as mentioned by Tall Paul thanks.

I have modified my function witch was saving data and after save was loaded again and again...

I'm using now

```
self.update_column(:zysk, 400)
```

To not use callbacks.